# Firebase onAuthStateChanged listener never fires on localhost despite being authorized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Fairly experienced with Firebase, encountering a strange and unintuitive bug. I've written a Firebase authentication wrapper using the React Context API, and track the currently logged in user with a listener. Here is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Registering firebase auth listener");

  const unsubscribe = fa.onAuthStateChanged(
    fa.getAuth(),
    function (user) {
      console.log(user);
      setCurrentUser(user);
    },
    (error) => console.error(error),
    () => console.warn("Firebase listener unhooked")
  );

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Up until recently, this worked fine, but something has caused it to stop working **only on localhost** with no error message. The print at the top for checking that the hook runs gets logged, but nothing else.

[image: Localhost is approved in the firebase dashboard]

I don't understand what's going on here. Is there something obvious I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem. I'd accidentally removed the initialization of firebase. To anyone reading this, if your onAuthStateChanged is mysteriously not firing, **make sure you run initializeApp first.**

If you're importing the intialization from another module, **make sure you import the initialization code first**.